moment generating function of the Borel distribution
Calculate the moment generating function of the Borel distribution given by $P(X=x; \mu) = \frac{e^{-\mu x} (\mu x)^{x-1}}{x!}$
with $\mu \in (0,1)$ and $x = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$.

Welcome to MSE, André! There's a trick to do that. But if you don't know the trick... I explained it in my answer

Also, if you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'll be glad to help you with this one

This is a PSQ.
Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

The pmf for the Borel distribution of parameter $\mu\in(0,1)$ is
$$\mathbb P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\mu x}(\mu x)^{x-1}}{x!}=\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!},$$
for $x=1,2,3,\dots$
Let $\alpha:=\mu e^{-\mu}$. Raising both sides to $x-1$ we get $\alpha^{x-1}=\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu(x-1)}. $ Multiplying both sides by $e^{-\mu}$ we get the identity
$$e^{-\mu}\alpha^{x-1}=\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu x}.$$
Substituting this identity into the following we get
\begin{align}1&=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\ 
&=\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{-\mu}\alpha^{x-1}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\
&=\frac1\alpha e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=1}^\infty\alpha^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}.
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by $\alpha e^\mu$, we get
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\alpha^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!} = \alpha\, e^\mu=\mu.$$
Consider the function $g:(0,1)\to(0,e^{-1}),\:g(\nu):=\nu e^{-\nu}$.
We have found that
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty [g(\nu)]^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!} = \nu,\quad\forall\nu\in(0,1).$$
Since $g'>0$, the function $g$ is invertible, thus we also get that $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\beta^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!} = g^{-1}(\beta),\quad\forall\beta\in(0,e^{-1}).$$
Let's compute the moment generating function $M_X(t)$.
\begin{align}
M_X(t)&=\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})=\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx}\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\ &=\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx}e^{-\mu}\alpha^{x-1}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha e^{\mu}}\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx}\alpha^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\ &=\frac1\mu\sum_{x=1}^\infty (\alpha e^t)^{x}\frac{x^{x-1}}{x!}\\
&=\frac1\mu g^{-1}(\alpha e^t)\\&=\frac1\mu g^{-1}( \mu e^{-\mu}e^t)=\frac1\mu g^{-1}\bigl( g(\mu)\,e^t\bigr)\\&=\frac1\mu g^{-1}\bigl( \mu e^{-(\mu-t)}\bigr)
\end{align}
Thus, the mgf is
$$M_X(t)=\frac1\mu g^{-1}\bigl( \mu e^{-(\mu-t)}\bigr),$$
which is well defined for $t\in(-\infty,\mu+\log\frac1\mu -1)$.
Finally note that \begin{align}M_X(0)&=\frac1\mu g^{-1}\bigl( g(\mu)\bigr)=\frac1\mu\mu=1,\\
M_X'(0)&=\frac1\mu\left.\frac{g(\mu)\,e^t}{g'\Bigl(g^{-1}\bigl(g(\mu)\,e^t\bigr)\Bigr)}\right\rvert_{t=0}\\&=\frac1\mu\frac{g(\mu)}{g'\Bigl(g^{-1}\bigl(g(\mu)\bigr)\Bigr)}\\&=\frac1\mu\frac{\mu e^{-\mu}}{g'(\mu)}=\frac{e^{-\mu}}{(1-\mu)e^{-\mu}}\\&=\frac{1}{1-\mu}=\mathbb E(X),
\end{align}
according to the theory.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Hi Anne, I didn't know there were such strict policies. When answering to new users' questions, all the warnings I read are about being kind with new contributors, which I totally agree with and also did. But being polite to people, which is part of common sense, is something you expect to find in a policy; on the other hand, the requirement on new users about providing proofs of their own effort is something which is not obvious to find in a policy at all.

You could simply have warned me without deleting the work I put in for providing a detailed answer, just for the chance it may encourage low-quality questions.

I did not delete anything, I only recalled you and André (with many links) the requirements on this site, which are the same for all users.

Oh, I see. Thank you, Anne!
